I'm looking for a praat script that measures the voiced portion of a consonant closure marked in a textgrid
Does anyone have or know of a praat script that can measure the voiced portion of segments that are marked on a textgrid in praat? Like, say I had a conversation and I had every /d/ spoken in that conversation's closure transcribed in a praat textgrid, how might I extract the duration of the voiced portion of every d's closure? Preferably to a txt file or something similar.

this is what you are looking for. https://github.com/JalalAl-Tamimi/Praat-Voicing-detection
